# Accessing Riak node from a remote machine (riak-admin backup)

Tags: amazon-ec2, riak

While trying to run a `riak-admin backup riak@ec2-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com riak /home/user/backup.dat all` on a remote machine (ec2 instance) I encounter the following error message

`{"init terminating in do_boot",{{nocatch,{could_not_reach_node,'riak@ec2-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com'}},[{riak_kv_backup,ensure_connected,1,[{file,"src/riak_kv_backup.erl"},{line,171}]},{riak_kv_backup,backup,3,[{file,"src/riak_kv_backup.erl"},{line,40}]},{erl_eval,do_apply,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,572}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}`

I assume there's a connection / permission error since the same backup command will work if run locally on the instance (with a local node ip of course), I should note the server (Node.js) can remotely connect to that ip so the port is open and accessible 8098). Any advice on how to make the backup operational remotely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the `riak-admin backup` command doesn't work remotely - and certainly it's not something I've ever tried to do. I'd recommend setting up a periodic backup (via cron or similar) and then use `rsync` to get your backup file down to local.

Alternatively, you could try the following hacky untested idea for a single script.

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh ec2-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com "riak-admin backup riak@ip-local-ec2 /home/user/backup.dat all"
rsync -avP ec2-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/user/backup.dat .
```